# How to put separate different string values into multiple lines in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have UITableView and within it, I am attempting to display two separate string values, each on a different line.  The second string or the amount should be displayed under the first line of text within the table view.

The code below displays how the text within the table view is constrained and other functions where I assume the function of separating the values into different lines will be issues:

```
    func set(bio: Bio){
    bioLabel.text = bio.statistics
    amountLabel.text = bio.amount
}

func configureBioLabel(){
    bioLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    bioLabel.textColor  = .systemGreen
    bioLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Seravek", size: 22)
    bioLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    
    
}

func setBioLabelConstraints(){
    bioLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bioLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    bioLabel.anchor(top: nil, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 50, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    bioLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    bioLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 16/9).isActive = true
}

func configureAmount(){
    amountLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    amountLabel.textColor = .systemYellow
    amountLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Seravek", size: 22)
    amountLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
}

func setAmountLabelConstriants(){
    amountLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    amountLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    amountLabel.anchor(top: nil, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 50, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    amountLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    amountLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

Then in this extension, the separate sting values are added to the table view.

```
    extension BioInfo: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return bio.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: BioCellId.bioCellId) as! CustomBioCell
    let bios = bio[indexPath.row]
    cell.set(bio: bios)
    return cell
}


}

struct Bio{
var statistics: String
var amount: String
}

extension BioInfo{

func fetchData() -> [Bio]{

    let info = Bio(statistics: "Text", amount: "0")
    
    let info2 = Bio(statistics: "Text", amount: "0")
    
    let info3 = Bio(statistics: "Text", amount: "0")
    
    return [info, info2, info3]
    
}
}
```

My table view cells are defined here:

```
    class BioInfo: UICollectionViewCell{
lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
         let tblView = UITableView()
         tblView.delegate = self
         tblView.dataSource = self
         tblView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         return tblView
   }()

var bio: [Bio] = []



struct BioCellId {
    static let bioCellId = "CustomBioCell"
}



override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    

    bio = fetchData()
    setupTableView()

}
func setupTableView() {

    addSubview(tableView)
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 350, left: 0, bottom: 300, right: 0),size: .init(width: frame.width, height: 300))
    
    
    tableView.rowHeight = 100
    
    tableView.register(CustomBioCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: BioCellId.bioCellId)


}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: where are your cells defined?

Comment: @johnelemans Well I put the UITableView cell within a collection view cell.  So I'll update it.

Comment: @johnelemans. I put the code defining my cells.

Comment: The first line is the `textLabel` of the cell, the second line is the `detailTextLabel` of the cell. Make sure to set the style of your cell to `.subtitle`.

Comment: why are you making a table in the cell? You can define two UILabelViews and display the two strings in them.